# How to push to origin master in Git?

Tags: git

I am new to Git and I am teaching myself because tomorrow I have to teach other students about Git. I am trying to do something simple: Create a repository, add a file, commit changes and push to origin master.

I created a repository in my local machine, I added a file, I committed the changes the only problem now is that it gives me an error when I try to push to origin master.

I went to my Github account and I created a new folder because I thought that maybe that's what I need to do, however yesterday I was very overwhelmed by everything. I put up a whole presentation about Git using PowerShell for my students and I fell asleep.

Today I am trying to get back on track. I am in PowerShell again and I have absolutely no idea what to do.

How do I push to origin master?

Comment: It gives you an error... Maybe we can help if you tell us about that error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "how do I?" question about a simple operation on github. They provide ample documentation, as well as human support. There is no reason to duplicate their documentation on SO.

Comment: Update. I tried again. So I went to my repo and then I did a: git init and then I did a git remote add [url], then I did a git add [file], then I did a git commit -m "[message]" but it gives me this message: On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: _"it gives me an error when I try to push to origin master"_ - what's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for you will be to start over.

Create an empty repo on github, clone the repo down to your machine, make a change, and then push it back.

Github has excellent docs for how to do this, as well as how to do more complex things. There's really no reason to ask on SO.

Comment: I did what you just told me. I created an empty repo on github, cloned the repo added a file, then committed, then did a git push origin master and nothing happened. I didn't get an error but I don't see anything on github

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way you can use is

> **Open your folder** 
> **Git Bash** From there (Don't forget to connect your Git account before)
> **$ git status** to see if there are any changes to the working directory and files located in untraceable and traceable
> **$ git add**  to change the state of the file/directory to staged
> ** $ git commit -m “message”** to insert snapshot data into git database,
> change `message` with the message as needed, for example `initial commit`.

Then

> $ git remote add origin https://github.com/insertyourRepository to add
> remotes 
> $ git remote -v to see a list of remotes
> $ git pull origin master to pull information from remote origin
> $ git pull origin master to pull information from remote origin

There you go